# artisan key generate error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to duplicate a laravel project on my local machine (windows, wamp, laravel 5.4)

I copied all the files and folders beside the vendor folder to a new folder.

I ran `composer install`, `artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`

But, when I ran `artisan key:generate` I get this error:

> file_put_contents: failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied.

Why is that and how do I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: check directory permission, storage directory should be writable

Comment: check permissions on .env file, first check if it's read-only and if it is ... remove read-only flag

Comment: @Bost, it holds no relevance over .env. It's the Storage/logs that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Option, `php artisan key:generate` write new key as a value of APP_KEY parameter in .env file. So .env file should be writeable by user running it. If it's read-only it will fail.

Comment: Its 100% the Storage folder @Bostjan

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

`chmod -R 777 storage/*`

sometimes `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*`

then `php artisan cache:clear`

then `php artisan key:generate`

This is due to the file permissions not being writeable. Seems to be quite a regular occurrence this happens but the steps above will rectify your problem.

To utilise more of these commands on a windows you can use a program called Git Bash. It's a very neat and handy tool: [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)

**If you do not wish to use git bash you can take this approach:**

Locate the Storage folder within your file explorer. Right click and press permissions and change the security permissions to allow write access.

Comment: Thank you but as I said, I am using Windows, there is no chmod or sudo in windows.

Comment: @Sigal, I'd suggest looking into a program called git bash. This will open many more terminal commands for you. I use it on a windows system myself.

Comment: thx, but I can't sit and learn another thing right now. I don't understand what is the connection between the env file and the storage folder either

Comment: Storage/ holds your logs. Is this on a server or your localhost?

Comment: My local host, wamp, windows 7

Comment: Ok so locate the Storage folder within your file browser. right click and press permissions and change the security permissions to allow write access.

Comment: right click-properties-Security-Allow All getting an error Access is denied, but after that the permissions are given, yet key generate gives the same error. Going to restart the computer and see if it helps

Comment: @Sigal, without utilising the command line to your advantage laravel is going to be a struggle as a majority of your commands are done via the command line. I'd strongly suggest looking up Git Bash.

Comment: thank you very much for trying to help. I managed to build a whole site with windows command line, but I will look into Git Bash.

Comment: @Sigal, did you rectify this problem in the end?

Comment: nope. Installed Git bash, ran the commands you offered to run, still getting the same error.

Comment: file_put_contents (c:\wamp\www\mysite.local/.env): failed to open stream: Permission denied. And the env file is not Read only

Comment: @Sigal, in git bash once you're in the directory type `ls -l` this will show you permissions.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 1 Zigal 197121      0 Nov  3 08:04 app/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Zigal 197121   1646 Mar 14  2017 artisan*
drwxr-xr-x 1 Zigal 197121      0 Apr 28  2017 bootstrap/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Zigal 197121    453 Nov 14 16:14 live.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 Zigal 197121      0 Apr 28  2017 nbproject/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Zigal 197121      0 Oct  2 15:34 storage/

Can't post everything it showed but maybe this helps?